# Access Label Tag in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I am trying to change the placeholder "Company Name (optional) to "Child's Name".

I'm not able to edit the HTML directly, but I can use a JavaScript file. I'm trying to access the below HTML with a JavaScript file.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input class="not-required" id="company" name="company"
 type="text" value="">
  <label alt="Company Name (optional)" placeholder="Company Name (optional)"></label>
</div>
```

The code below adds "Child's Name" to the `<input>`, but I would like to add it to the `<label>` instead.  The label does not have an id or class.  Is there a way to change the label placeholder from "Company Name (optional) to "Child's Name"?

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("company").placeholder = "Child's Name";     
}
myFunction();
```

Comment: You need to select label not the input if you want to change label

Comment: Yes, how do I select the label without an id or class?

Comment: Like this `document.querySelector("#company + label").textContent = 'Child's Name';` ...which work with the existing markup.

Comment: @LGSon Single to double quotes: `'Child's Name'` --> `"Child's Name"` so the quote isn't closed too early.

Comment: @jkdev Yes, thanks...my mistake, forgot the inner single quote. Or one escape the inner with a backslash

Comment: @LGSon I posted my own answer, but yours should work as an answer as well.

Comment: @jkdev No...there's enough with answers now :)

Comment: @LGSon May I add your code to my answer?

Comment: @jkdev Yes, of course...and thanks for asking, and upvoted

Answer (score 5):

#### Solution 1

```
// Get label element, which is next element sibling of input element
var inputElement = document.getElementById("company");
var labelElement = inputElement.nextElementSibling;

// Set label element's content
labelElement.textContent = "Child's Name";
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
document.getElementById("company").nextElementSibling.textContent = "Child's Name";
```

Note: `nextElementSibling` returns the next element, while `nextSibling` returns the next element, text node, or comment node. So in this case, using `nextSibling` would insert the text content before the label element, not inside it.

#### Solution 2

Courtesy [LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2827823/lgson).

```
// Get label element using selector
var labelElement = document.querySelector("#company + label");

// Set label element's content
labelElement.textContent = "Child's Name";
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
document.querySelector("#company + label").textContent = "Child's Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var el = document.getElementById("company-name-label");
el.textContent = "Child's Name";
el.alt = "Child's Name";
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input class="not-required" id="company" name="company" type="text" value="">
  <label alt="Company Name (optional)" id="company-name-label"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript. I have JavaScript that rearranging bug reporting system pages. It’s not fun, or pretty code, but it works

Answer (score 0):

Know that `alt` and `placeholder` are not valid attributes for a `<label>` tag.

As you claim that you cannot change the HTML, you can use the `nextElementSibling` from the `<input>` reference to access the `<label>`.

Inside your `<div>`, the child elements `<input>` and `<label>` are siblings of each other.

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("company").nextElementSibling.innerText = "Child's Name";
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input class="not-required" id="company" name="company" type="text" value="">
  <label>Company Name (optional)</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Paul,  This almost works, but the label placeholder still shows up in the form.  I can hide it with CSS, but that also hides the placeholder text.  I really appreciate the answer though.  I think it puts me on the right track.

Comment: I don't know where you are seeing a placeholder? It is not with your input, and placeholder is not a valid attribute for a label, so it should not appear.

Comment: (continued) ... I also re-added those attributes, and I cannot reproduce what you see. So, something has changed, or there is more to know. I also tried with the same attributes on Firefox and Chrome, but I cannot reproduce the situation. What browser are you using? (and the version, if it might matter)

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm trying to make this change within a platform called Cratejoy.  I'm using Chrome as my browser.  The Cratejoy HTML file shows placeholders.  Here is more of the HTML code for the section I'm trying to change with the JavaScript file:

Comment: <form method="POST" action="/checkout/checkout2" id="checkout_form">  
   <div class="cart_addresses">
    <div class="ship_to form_holder">
     <section>
      <h3 data-barley="checkout_shipping_title" data-barley-editor="plus">Shipping Address</h3>
       <div class="editor ">
 <div class="row">

Comment: <div class="col-md-6">
  <input autocomplete="shipping given-name" id="first_name" name="first_name" required="" type="text" value="" style="background-image: url(); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;"><label alt="First Name" placeholder="First Name"></label>
 </div>
  
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <input autocomplete="shipping family-name" id="last_name" name="last_name" required="" type="text" value=""><label alt="Last Name" placeholder="Last Name"></label>
 </div>
 
</div>

Comment: <div class="row">

 <div class="col-md-12">
  <input class="not-required" id="company" name="company" type="text" value=""><label alt="Company Name (optional)" placeholder="Company Name (optional)"></label>
 </div>
 
</div>

Comment: Well, the Cratejoy would be a big missing piece. I took a look at some of their stuff, and what you have differs from some of their examples. Plus, that appears to be a paid service? If so, I'd have THEIR support tell you how to work with these changes. (or they would lose my business if they did not) There also seems to be differences if you have Swift vs other platforms that they support -- as well as an "old interface" and a "new interface". Unfortunately, my help on this matter will be limited.

Answer (score 0):

You ask the input tag to behave like a label. You can directly access your label tag and change it.

Just add an id to your label tag and then insert this id into your `getElementById`.

If you want to change the displayed text, use `.innerHTML` or `.innerText`

Comment: I wish I could do this, but I don't have access to the HTML.  So I would need to add the id to the label with JavaScript.  But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You can take the element in js without touch the html. `getElemetByTagName("label")`, or if you have more then one you can make `.querySelector("label:XnthChild")` for example (change the `X` to what you need)

Comment: Hi Yosi, It appears to be the 3rd label, should this work?  .querySelector("label:3nthChild")

Comment: the correct syntax is `label:nth-child(3)`, and yes it should work.
[this docs can help](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)